# Webservice client code to include secuirty header as per oracle/wss10_x509_token_with_message_protection_client_policy

Tags: oracle, web-services, soap, weblogic, jax-ws

Need code snippet for adding security header in SOAP request as per policy oracle/wss10_x509_token_with_message_protection_client_policy. I have tried using below code. But when i hit the webservice then its saying in server logs: oracle.wsm.security.SecurityException: WSM-00069 : The security header is missing. Ensure that there is a valid security policy attached at the client side, and the policy is enabled.

**Code:**

```
EntMsgEvsNotificationBindingQSService service = new EntMsgEvsNotificationBindingQSService();
SecurityPoliciesFeature securityFeatures = new SecurityPoliciesFeature(new String[] { "bankaudi/wss10_x509_token_client_policy" });
EntMsgEvsNotification port = service.getEntMsgEvsNotificationBindingQSPort(securityFeatures);

List credProviders = new ArrayList();  
CredentialProvider cp =   
                    new ClientBSTCredentialProvider(clientKeyStore, clientKeyStorePass,   
                            clientKeyAlias, clientKeyPass,   
                            "JKS",serverCert); 
            System.out.println("Credential Provider"+cp);
            credProviders.add(cp);   

BindingProvider bindingProvider = (BindingProvider) port;
            bindingProvider.getRequestContext()
            .put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, endPoint);
            Map<String, Object> requestContext =   
                    ((BindingProvider)port).getRequestContext();   
requestContext.put(WSSecurityContext.CREDENTIAL_PROVIDER_LIST,   credProviders);   
            requestContext.put(ClientConstants.WSSEC_KEYSTORE_TYPE,"JKS");   
            requestContext.put(ClientConstants.WSSEC_KEYSTORE_LOCATION,clientKeyStore);   
            requestContext.put(ClientConstants.WSSEC_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD,clientKeyStorePass);   
            requestContext.put(ClientConstants.WSSEC_ENC_KEY_ALIAS,serverAlias);   
            requestContext.put(ClientConstants.WSSEC_ENC_KEY_PASSWORD,clientKeyPass);   
            requestContext.put(ClientConstants.WSSEC_RECIPIENT_KEY_ALIAS,serverAlias);   
            requestContext.put(ClientConstants.WSSEC_SIG_KEY_ALIAS,clientKeyAlias);   
            requestContext.put(ClientConstants.WSSEC_SIG_KEY_PASSWORD,clientKeyPass);
requestContext.put(WSSecurityContext.TRUST_MANAGER,   
                    new TrustManager() {   
                public boolean certificateCallback(X509Certificate[] chain,   
                        int validateErr) {   
                    // Check that the server cert matches   
                    boolean result = true;   
                    return result;   
                }   
            });
```

Comment: Have you checked what XML is actually sent by your app? It's common to encounter problems with a server not understanding a valid message from a client.

Comment: Yes. Header is not there in the request xml.